# How to install MetPy?

Tags: metpy

I am new to python and my professor would like to me to plot graphs on MetPy for my undergraduate research project. I am confused on how to install this program into python. I haven't used pip before and I've tried using command prompt and the python shell, but nothing has really worked. I have never used pip before.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/installguide.html ?

Comment: How was Python installed on your system?

Answer (score 0):

If your Python is installed and managed using Conda (e.g. Anaconda or Miniconda), you can install MetPy from the conda-forge channel:

```
conda install -c conda-forge metpy
```

If you have Python installed from Python.org or are using your system's install of Python (not recommended), you first need to [install pip](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-pip-for-python/). Then do:

```
pip install metpy
```